# Beaglebone Black doesn't obtain 169.254.xxx.xxx IP

Tags: ip-address

If i connect my Beaglebone Black, which runs on **Angstrom**, to my computer via ethernet cable, It obtains an IP address, which starts with 169.254.xxx.xxx, for communication purposes. And I can communicate with it using TCP protocols. I can see that IP address when I use "ifconfig" command in terminal. But If it runs on Android, it doesn't obtain an IP address. Since there isn't "ifconfig" command in Android terminal, I'm using "netcfg" to see IP information and it shows that Beaglebone doesn't have an IP address. I need to somehow "force" my Beaglebone Black to obtain an IP address (like 169.254.xxx.xxx). How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I can give a static IP to my Beaglebone via shell scripts (or adb):

ifconfig eth0 up 169.254.13.13